# How can I align text to the bottom left of an image of unknown size?

Tags: css

I have images on my page that are different sizes. I am trying to place text in the bottom left and right of the image that shows who uploaded it and how many favourites it has. There is currently text in the center. How can I get the text to be in the same place on each image?

I have tried this but on taller images the gap is larger

**My Code**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Browse</h1>
        <div class="grid" data-isotope='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "layoutMode": "layout" }'>
            <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
            <?php
            while ($row = $get_images->fetch()) {?>
                <a class="grid-item" href="image.php?id=<?php echo $row['image_id']; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row['image_url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['image_title']; ?>">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text"><?php echo $row['image_title']; ?></div>
                        <div class="uploaded-by"><?php echo $row['username'];?></div>
                        <div class="favourites"><?php echo $row['image_earned_points'];?></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            <?php }?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**My CSS** (so far)

```
.grid-item {
    float: left;
    padding: 2px;
}
.grid-item img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
  }
.grid-item img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.01);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s ease;
    background: rgba(33, 26, 33, 0.815);
}
.grid-item:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}
.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.uploaded-by {
    position: relative;
    top: 87%;
    right: 40%;
}
.favourites {
    position: relative;
    top: 70%;
    left: 40%;
}
```

The classes to look at are `uploaded-by` which needs to be in the bottom left, and `favourites` would be bottom right.

And image can be found here of what it outputs [example](http://oi66.tinypic.com/2djcirk.jpg)

Comment: Maybe a `<br />` after `<div class="overlay">`? I have no idea what you're code will produce. If you can supply the final html and css it would be easier. Create a demo in jsfiddle, with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}

p {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;    
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    bottom: 5px;
}

#left {
    left: 20px;
}

#right {
    right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg"/>
    <p id="left">Hello</p>
    <p id="right">World!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm playing with this at the moment and it's almost working.

Comment: You're welcome. If you run into any specific issues, let me know.

Comment: Alright, it's sorted! I had to change bottom a little and i applied some extra styling to the #left and #right, some margins and its all looking great on every image.